# GitHub Pages website not running the same as when its run locally using live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I'm currently making a small website where someone can type in an anagram and the site will return all the possible words that can be made from the anagram. Once all the words have been returned, you can click on a word to give all of its definitions.

The site works fine when I run it locally using live server, the issue is when I deploy the repository using GitHub Pages.

When run locally, when I enter a word (e.g acres), the site will return all the possible words that can be found correctly, but when I do the same using GitHub Pages, the site won't return the same. All the logic related to finding all the possible words is in my script.js file so I'm guessing the issue might be in there? The script.js file reads in a dictionary.txt file to get a bank of words and filters through them to find the words that can be made from the anagram. The script.js file also deals with fetching the definitions of a given word from an external dictionary API and adding the data to the main html file.

Here's the script.js file. Sorry if it's a bit of a mess! I'm a bit new to coding JavaScript on the front end. I've also included the index.html and style.css files in case the issue might be in one of those.

```js
let inputElement = document.querySelector("#anagram-input");

inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);

let words = [];

fetch("dictionary.txt")
  .then(res => {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(dictionary => {
    words = dictionary.split("\n");
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      words[i] = words[i].slice(0, -1);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

function fetchDefinitions(e) {
  let chosenWord = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.textContent;
  fetch(`https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${chosenWord}/definitions`, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "API-KEY",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      let cardInnerElement = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
      cardInnerElement.style = "transform: rotateY(180deg)";
      let cardFrontElement = cardInnerElement.firstElementChild;
      cardFrontElement.style = "transform: rotateY(180deg)";
      addDefinitionsHTML(cardFrontElement, data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function addDefinitionsHTML(element, data) {
  let definitionsHTML;
  if (data.success === false || definitions.length === 0) {
    definitionsHTML = `No definition for this word is currently available. Sorry!`;
    element.lastElementChild.innerHTML = definitionsHTML;
    return;
  }
  definitionsHTML = `<p class="card-title" style="text-align: left">Definitions of ${data.word}:</p><ul>`;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.definitions.length; i++) {
    definitionsHTML += `<p style="text-align: left">${data.definitions[i].definition}</p>`;
  }
  definitionsHTML += `</ul>`;
  element.lastElementChild.innerHTML = definitionsHTML;
}

function onKeyUp(e) {
  let enteredWord = e.target.value;
  return findWordsFromAnagram(enteredWord);
}

function findWordsFromAnagram(anagram) {
  let filteredWordList = [];
  let finalWordList = [];
  anagram = anagram.toLowerCase().split("").sort();
  //filter the dictionary list by the length of the anagram
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length === anagram.length) {
      filteredWordList.push(words[i]);
    }
  }
  //make a copy of filteredWordList and sort all words inside alphabetically
  let sortedFilteredWordList = filteredWordList.map(x => x);
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedFilteredWordList.length; i++) {
    sortedFilteredWordList[i] = sortedFilteredWordList[i].split("").sort();
  }
  //Add any words from filteredWordList that have the same letters as anagram to finalWordList
  for (let i = 0; i < filteredWordList.length; i++) {
    let booleanTracker = true;
    for (let j = 0; j < anagram.length; j++) {
      if (sortedFilteredWordList[i][j] != anagram[j]) {
        booleanTracker = false;
      }
    }
    if (booleanTracker) {
      finalWordList.push(filteredWordList[i]);
    }
    booleanTracker = true;
  }
  return outputWordsFromAnagram(finalWordList);
}

function outputWordsFromAnagram(words) {
  let outputElement = document.querySelector("#output");
  let outputHTML = ``;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    outputHTML += `<div class="col-lg-12 col-m-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-3 flip-card">
                                <div class="text-center flip-card-front">
                                    <div class="card border-primary flip-card-inner">
                                        <div class="card-header"><h5>${words[i]}</h5></div>
                                        <div class="card-body text-primary">
                                            <p id="definitions" class="click">Click here for its definition!<p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
  }
  outputElement.innerHTML = outputHTML;
  let definitionElements = document.querySelectorAll("#definitions");
  for (let i = 0; i < definitionElements.length; i++) {
    definitionElements[i].addEventListener("click", fetchDefinitions);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.click:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

.flip-card {
  perspective: 1000px;
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Anagram App</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Anagram App</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="anagram-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Anagram">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div id="output" class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The link to the GitHub Pages is [here](https://jpjoe99.github.io/anagram-app/)

I've included screenshots of the results I get from both when I type in "acres" as the anagram.

- [GitHub Pages screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8R84.png)
- [Live Server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2XbS.png)

[Here is the link to the GitHub repository itself](https://github.com/JPjoe99/anagram-app)

I just can't figure out why it's not working the same as the local one. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem on your GitHub Pages site. It returns a number of words when I use `acres` as you show in the screen shot. The links return definitions. What am I missing? Are you sure you haven't cached and old/broken version?

Comment: You should probably remove the API key from your example

Comment: @RandyCasburn when I try it, the first two results are "cares", as in the GitHub Pages Screenshot. The local example shows "acres" as the first two results. So there seems to be a difference

Comment: OK, perhaps a platform issue then? me: macOS Big Sur and Safari 14.0.3.

Comment: @ferdynator completely forgot about removing that, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @ferdynator - works on Chrome 88 too.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm using Chrome 88 too but on Windows 10, do you think the fact that I'm using Windows could be the issue?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what my results looks like. I do realize there is doubt on this site at times: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm0Wn.png

Comment: Thanks for sending the screenshot! You seem to be getting the same results as me where it starts to duplicate certain words and miss out valid words that can be made from the anagram. I just can't seem to see why it's doing that? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: @RandyCasburn I did try clearing the cache but that didn't seem to change anything :/

Comment: Darn it @Joe - I mis interpreted the problem statement. Sorry for the waste of your time.

Comment: Ah no worries @RandyCasburn, thank you for your help though!

Comment: Are you getting same results but in different order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the dictionary that is returned (\n separated string), I could not figure out why you were removing the last character of each word of the word array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   words[i] = words[i].slice(0,-1);
}
```

When typing the letter 'a', that code is placing 24 'a', 24 'b', 24 'c'...24 'z' into the word array. So when attempting to find anagrams it is searching through these letter too.

I see no apparent reason to have that code. If you remove it produces the results you expect as far as I can tell.

Comment: After I split the dictionary text file into an array containing all of the words in the file, for some reason each element in the array had a space as the last character `words[0] = hello `

Comment: I was not seeing that while was debugging. But, if that's the case, just use `.trim()` on the string.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write more in the previous comment but I accidentally submitted it. I thought it was a bit weird that it was leaving a space at the end of each element in the array, I'm guessing it's not supposed to do that when using the `.slice()`? I'll try using `.trim()` instead and see what it gives, thanks Randy!

Comment: As I said, you don't need to do that at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: I thought I'd remove the splicing/trimming part of the code and double check to see if definitely does add a space at the end of each element. I used `a` as the anagram and checked the length of the first element of the words array as `words[0] = "a"` so the first element should definitely be shown as a result if the anagram is `a`. It came back that `word[0].length = 2` vs `anagram.length = 1`. I decided to use `.splice()` on `word[0]` and that came back with `["a", ""]`. I'm not sure where this `""` is coming from? I've linked a screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/2g4HaKt).

Comment: When you have an string of a single character 'a' and you splice(0,-1) the value that is returned and placed into your array is - wait for it - `""` - that gets shoved into the array as the first element. Then you do it again and viola - `["a",""]`. If your intent is to trim the string then (please?) use the mechanism designed to do that for you --> `.trim()`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I've changed the function to `.trim()` and it all works now! Thank you so much Randy!

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I could help! Have fun.